# Create Edge profile with custom name

Tags: browser, chromium, user-profiles, microsoft-edge

I want to create several Edge-profiles for my users. By running the following Powershell commands I can create two profiles:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -ArgumentList "--profile-directory=Profile-FOO --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check"

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -ArgumentList "--profile-directory=Profile-BAR --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check"
```

This creates two profile folders (`Profile-FOO` and `Profile-BAR`) within directory `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\`. This is fine so far.

However, in the profile selection the entries are displayed as `Profile 1` and `Profile 2`. This is quite unintuitive for the users since the can't distinguish the profiles.

[image: Generated profiles]

The only way to rename the profiles I found is by using the UI dialog `Edit profile` where the user can choose a profile name and an icon. But of course that's not a solution for me because I'm looking for a way to create named profiles without user interaction. Ideally, I would also automatically set a separate icon for each profile.

Has anyone a clue how to achieve this?